# PHP doesn't see bcmath

Tags: php, centos, devops

I've got two versions of PHP on a server(Centos 6.8) - 5.6 and 7.1
My Nginx using php7.1, which is not default PHP interpreter.
After some struggle with yum i've installed php71-php-bcmath. Yum didn't enable it by default, so i made a symlink

```
ln -s /opt/php71/etc/mods-available/bcmath.ini /opt/php71/etc/php.d/bcmath.ini
```

`/opt/php71/bin/php-config --extension-dir` shows that extension path is
/opt/php71/lib/php/modules

There IS bcmath.so

```
/opt/php71/bin/php -i | grep bcmath
```

show that php is cofigured with flag `'--enable-bcmath=shared'`

But when i'm trying to use function from bcmath - there is error

```
Call to undefined function PhpAmqpLib\Wire\bcadd()
```

I've already made nginx and php-fpm restart a thousand times, how can i enable this wicked extension?

Comment: If you run this on 7.1 
<?php
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
?>
does it list the bcmath extension?

Comment: `/opt/php71/bin/php -m`  shows `[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype`

Comment: added the extension in php.ini?

Comment: if i do this - there will be an error, cause I've already made a symlink to php.d

Comment: `PHP Warning:  Module 'bcmath' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`, if i write in php.ini  like `extension=bcmath.so`

Comment: `/opt/php71/bin/php -m` The `CLI` can use a separate PHP.ini file, so even if it's installed when checking by the command line, this may not be the case under Apache.  Just saying.  `php.ini` and `php-cli.ini` usually.  Also RabbitMq is nice ... :)  .... I run it in production on a CentOs7 server.

Comment: Thank you, but not, it doesn't work even this way, throgh ini, i've already tryed. I really don't know what the heck is going on with my php. I'm just trying to install some laravel repo for RabbitMQ queue with ampq functions and failing for two days already

Comment: Ok, i think now it is the time to start a new fantastic adventure - kill php 5.6 on a server, maybe this will help

Comment: with those package names, how will centos differentiate between php version 7.1.0 and the future php version 71.0.0  ?

Comment: So, i had been restarting wrong php-fpm, in my case it was php-fpm71, gosh, it had driven me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had been restarting wrong php-fpm, in my case it was php-fpm71